# Организация чата, многопоточность или массив пользователей?

Tags: сокет, c++, linux

Пишу сервер для чата. Протокол свой. Знакомый (друг) пишет клиент. Встал вопрос, как организовать обслуживание нескольких клиентов.

Первый вариант. Прослушка каждого сокета - отдельный поток. Отсюда вопрос: "Насколько это ресурсоемко выйдет по сравнению во вторым вариантом?"

Второй вариант. 3 потока. Первый принимает новые подключения и добавляет пользователей например в "вектор". Второй пробегает по "вектору", принимая данные. Третий отсылает таким же образом.

Приму также совет по алгоритму реализации.

Comment: В новые сокеты кидайте каждое подключение.

Comment: Я бы поизучал исходники Jabber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько ресурсоемко зависит от количества клиентов. Если их будет не много, выбирайте любой вариант, будет работать, если грамотно реализовать.
В ином случае есть минусы у обоих предложенных вариантов:

1. Для первого - множество потоков. Время на создание потока тоже затрачивается и т.п.
2. Для второго - размер буфера. Здесь вытекают недостатки: как хранить данные для отправки (полученные от др. клиентов); скорость обработки каждого из векторов (списков) и т.д.
3. А если попробовать скомбинировать оба варианта? Выделять один поток, например, для 10 клиентов, придется помучатся с обработкой, но вы компенсируете недостатки своих вариантов.
4. А не пойти бы на новую ступень? Организация p2p чата с сервером. Сервер только знает кто в сети и их идентификаторы, а клиенты обмениваются сообщениями без участия сервера.